# Linux update affects Windows in dual-boot?

Tags: linux, multi-boot, grub, windows-11, bitlocker

I have the following fresh dualboot setup on my laptop:

- Windows 11 Pro + Rocky Linux 9 on separate partitions
- EFI secure boot in use

I enabled filesystem encryption on Rocky Linux when installing it beside Windows. Yesterday I also encrypted the Windows installation with BitLocker.

However, this morning when I booted to Windows, I was greeted by BitLocker which said there has been some change in the machine configuration (it suggested possibly I have inserted some disc or USB device, and it might work if I just disconnect such). Luckily I had my BitLocker key available so I was able to get to the Windows setup.

The only thing I can think of that happened yesterday was that I ran updates for Rocky Linux, which created a new Rocky Linux entry into the GRUB boot menu. So when before that there were four entries in the grub boot menu:

1. Rocky Linux
2. Rocky Linux rescue mode
3. Windows 11
4. BIOS/UEFI firmware settings

now there were 5, and Windows was bumped to #4 on that list.

Any ideas what could be the possible causes for Windows BitLocker to feel the machine configuration had changed? Hopefully Windows BitLocker doesn't get a hissy fit every time I get some major update to Linux...

Comment: Encrypted or not, for ANY dual-boot configuration with Windows it's imperative to disable its Fast Startup feature.

Comment: Actually I did that, even though I was unsure if it will affect dualboot..

Comment: Maybe the answer is somewhere here:
https://community.sophos.com/encryption/f/discussion/110608/encryption-recovery-key-needed-after-pc-configuration-change
I don't recall touching the BIOS boot order yesterday, but can't fully recall...
Funny thing he mentions that BitLocker recovery has been triggered in Dell laptops with a docking station... and this laptop is Dell, and I booted from a docking station when the BitLocker recovery was triggered...

Comment: Unless you have a heavy duty Linux workload, better and safer to put Linux in a Virtual Machine.

Comment: I want to run the Linux system separately from Windows, not as a VM within Windows.

Comment: You made configuration changes. Configuration changes required you to input the BitLocker recovery key. If those updates result in a configuration change, they absolutely will result, in you inputting the recovery key.

Comment: I want to run the Linux system separately from Windows,  .. Then you have to accept the very large risks.

Comment: Ramhound: "You made configuration changes."
I guess my question was, do Linux (kernel?) updates constitute as such configuration changes from BitLocker's point of view, in a dual-boot system?

Comment: "Then you have to accept the very large risks."
What are the top 5 very large risks running Windows and Linux in dual-boot?
Just wondering since I've been doing that ever since like 20 years ago, and doing it at this very moment on several separate PC systems...

Comment: Changes in Windows boot structure (UEFI) is the biggest and most problematic risk that was not there 2 decades ago. I dropped Dual Boot back then

Comment: @John Funny thing, I did it more than ever. The UEFI boot mode is a lot more multi-boot friendly because bootloaders can co-exist and any proper UEFI system can boot anything directly, whereas before we had to rely on Grub (or others like LiLo) once we installed the Linux part. If we ever wanted to get back to Windows only we had to reinstall the Windows bootloader. UEFI is much better for that. While I agree that VMs are better for some users I feel that you often suggest it when it isn't proper. Now I finally understand that's a knee-jerk reaction due to your own bias.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I re-installed the Linux, and updated it again, and it didn't trigger Bitlocker recovery.

So I can conclude that the GRUB menu changing was not what triggered it. Most probably I did change some BIOS/UEFI boot option, e.g. the order of the Windows/Linux boots, which caused it.

Oh well, just need to keep the recovery key available, in case I trigger it again.

Comment: Usually the default configuration of grub is to set Linux as default OS to be booted. If this change is applied and you had Windows as default boot OS, Bitlocker will detect a UEFI change and you need the recovery key. As this only happens if there is a grub update it does not happen every time you install updates.